# Finish before hanging units and tiling

Tags: drywall

[image][image]

I have a company working with us in fitting a new kitchen. When they removed the old tiles, the plasterboard was damaged. They fitted new plasterboard. Should they have done anything to the new plasterboard to finish it before hanging cabinets? Also I am getting the backsplash tiled and in a couple of areas (as shown in picture with my hand) there is a considerable gap between worktop and plasterboard. How on earth does that get tiled without having to try fill the gaps with sealant/ silicone?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

The walls should have the seams taped and then primed, especially where tile will be installed. The area where your hand is inserted looks like the drywall needs to be shimmed out or refitted to be even with the worktop, unless it's the worktop that's not straight, unlikely.